# How to call an object constructor inside another constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I have an abstract class `A` and a class `B` with the constructor:

```
B(A &a) {...}
```

Now, I create these objects in the main program as follow:

```
int main(){
  std::unique_ptr<A> a = make_A();//don't mind make_A()
  if(a==null)
    a = make_default_A();
  B b (*a); 
}
```

Now I created a class which setups the system:

```
class System{
public:
  System();
private:
  B b;
  std::unique_ptr<A> a;
}
```

And the constructor is:

```
System(){
  a = make_A();
  if(a==null)
    a = make_default_A();
  b(*a);
}
```

Obviously this is wrong because I can't call `B`'s constructor as in the code above, but I can't figure out how to do this. The only solution that came to my mind is to use `std::unique_ptr<B> b;` instead of `B b;` and then call `b = make<B> (*a);`.

Comment: `b = B(*a);`should re-initialized `b` (note that its first initialization happens before the constructor is entered)

Comment: Or perhaps you can go for overloading the `=` operator and perform the same thing

Comment: @AndyG - *initialize* has a very specific meaning in C++, and `b = B(*a);` does *not* initialize `b` - it assigns to it.

Comment: I edited the question a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
class System{
public:
  System() : a(make_A()), b(*a) {} // use initializer list for constructor
private:
  // Fix order of members to initialize in correct order.
  std::unique_ptr<A> a;
  B b;
};
```

Comment: I edited the question, please give a look at it.

Comment: Created a function `MakeAOrDefault`.

Comment: Lol that makes sense